# Read in datas of the Periodic Table of Elements (pgfplotstable)

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

[image]

I tried to open 
https://gist.github.com/robertwb/22aa4dbfb6bcecd94f2176caa912b952 
(see above) with `pgfplotstable`. But I get several errors and warnings:

```
Package pgfplots Error: Table 'Periodic Table of Elements.csv' appears to have too many columns in l
ine 25: Ignoring ''. PGFPlots found that the number of columns is larger than t
he previously determined number of columns. Please verify that every cell entry
 is separated correctly (use braces {<cell entry>} if necessary. Also verify th
at column names are plain ASCII.). This error is not critical.
```

Could somebody say me what I have to do?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, showframe=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{Periodic Table of Elements.csv}{\psetable}

\begin{document}
\section{Table -- does not work}
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\psetable}

\section{Element -- does not work}
%\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{1}\of{\psetable}
%\pgfplotsretval
\end{document}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? At least an excerpt of error messages you are seeing is probably needed in order to help :)

Comment: Added. .........

Comment: If you look at line 25, you can see that the entry for discoverer is `"Gahn, Scheele"`, the comma is interpreted as a separator, so the number of columns is off. The error message also tells you, what to do: `use braces {<cell entry>}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says:

> Package pgfplots Error: Table 'Periodic Table of Elements.csv' appears to have too many columns in l
> ine 25: Ignoring ''. PGFPlots found that the number of columns is larger than t
> he previously determined number of columns. Please verify that every cell entry is separated correctly (use braces {} if necessary. Also verify that column names are plain ASCII.). This error is not critical.

And if you inspect line 25, you see:

`25,Manganese,Mn,54.938,30,25,25,4,7,solid,,yes,yes,,,Transition Metal,1.8,1.55,7.434,7.44E+00,1519.15,2334,11,"Gahn, Scheele",1774,0.479,4,`

The culprit that causes the error is `"Gahn, Scheele"`which is interpreted as two columns.  You need to replace the quotation marks with braces, as the error states. In the csv file there are only three lines with quotation marks, so you can do it by hand, or run `sed` on it:

```
sed 's_\"_\{_; s_\"_\}_'
```

After fixing the remaining unicode errors, your code almost runs. `\pgfplotstablegetelem` takes the name of the row as the second parameter or you have to use `[index]` to give a numeric value. Either

```
\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{[index]1}\of{\psetable}
```

or

```
\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{Element}\of{\psetable}
```

will work.

Comment: Ah ok, I replaced the commas by semicolas. That seems easier.